# Unable to alert the number (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        input:in-range {
            border: 2px solid red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="a" type="number" min="5" max="10" value="7">
    <script>   
        var aa = document.getElementById("a").value;
        aa.addEventListener("blur", b);
        function b() {
            if (aa >= 11) {
                alert("enter the no in range");
                return;
            }
            else {
                alert("Thats Great");

            }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

//  In the above code I am taking help of blur event for alerting the message when user enter the no greater than 10.
But after giving any value in the input I am not getting any alert message

Comment: You can't attach events to a string. Haven't you checked the console, there are some error messages waiting for you.

Comment: var aa = parseInt(document.getElementById("a").value); I have tried this also ,but is saying aa.addEventListener is not a function .

Comment: You tried to "listen" an event from input value, not from input, use `var aa = document.getElementById("a")` instead of `var aa = document.getElementById("a").value`, and inside function `b()` use value of `aa` instead of `aa`. 

And also **learn at first, before starting to write a code or questions**

Comment: Well, events can't be attached to numbers either. You can attach events to `window`, `document` and HTMLEventTargets, which usually are DOM elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a probable reason might be that you are adding the listener to the value of the input (which is the data you enter) and not input (the HTML element). Please try to replace

```
var aa = document.getElementById("a").value;
```

to

```
var aa = document.getElementById("a");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<script>   

  function b(){
    var aa = document.getElementById("a").value;
    if(aa>=11){
        alert("enter the no in range");
    }
    else{
        alert("Thats Great"); 
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("blur",b);

</script>
```

I haven't checked if it works. But the script you have contains a lot of errors,
please spend some time on JS basics.

Comment: You could spend some time to create a non code-only answer too ..?

Answer (score 0):

```
  var aa = document.getElementById("a");
  var aaValue = aa.value;
  aa.addEventListener("blur", b);
  function b(){
    aaValue = aa.value;
    if(aaValue >=11){
      alert("enter the no in range");
      return;
    }
    else{
      alert("Thats Great"); 
    }
  }
```

Comment: i just thought of like if element is class which is multiple nodes

for referring first element of node for EX:

document.getElementsByClassName('a');
aa[0].addEventListener("blur", b); // attaching event for first element

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

You where used `aa = document.getElementById("a").value` and try to add listener to 'aa'. Actually the 'aa' now contains the value of the element. So we can't bind an event to the input element. please try the following modified answer.

```js
var elementInput = document.getElementById("numElement");
elementInput.addEventListener("blur",alertFn, true);

       
 function alertFn() {
            if (elementInput.value >= 11) {
                alert("enter the no in range");
                return;
            }
            else {
                alert("Thats Great");

            }
          }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        input:in-range {
            border: 2px solid red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="numElement" type="number" min="5" max="10" value="7"/>
</body>

</html>
```

Another option is you can directly call the onblur event from the element itself

```
 <input id="numElement" type="number" min="5" max="10" value="7" onblur="alertFn(this.value)/>
```

Then the javascript become

```
function alertFn(data) {
            if (data >= 11) {
                alert("enter the no in range");
                return;
            }
            else {
                alert("Thats Great");

            }
          }
```

Comment: @Teemu changed document.getElementById("a").value to  document.getElementById("a")

Comment: @Teemu I will do